# Get the Sum by last date of the month in Quicksight for Historically aggregated data and Present live data

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I am working on a project to calculate the number of employees in the company. I have historical data of the Total employees of the company aggregated Monthly until October and daily data from November. we get total employees in the system daily at record level and for historical data, i have employees in the company at the end of the month, that also record level, i.e for every employee i have a record. Eg : For Historic data(before November 2021) if the number of employees at end of month in october 2021 is 50, we have 50 records with date as '20211031' and for September if we have 45 employees at end of month we have 45 records with date as 20210930 but from November we have these records daily.i,e if employees on Nov1 is 51 we have 51 records and if on Nov 2 if its 52 we will have 52 records with that date.

I want to calculate how many people are there in the system monthly. For historical its easy since we have only 1 date. for new daily data if we want employees for november we need to get data on that date. and if we move to december we need to show month end date of previous month as last month employee count and current month day's employee count as current month employee count.

This is how the data looks

```
Emp_id,name,count_value,date,Type
34567,xxxx,1,2021/09/30,HC
5678,yyyy,1,2021/09/30,HC
34567,xxxx,1,2021/10/31,HC
5678,yyyy,1,2021/10/31,HC
1234,,zzzz,1,2021/10/31,HC
34567,xxxx,1,2021/11/01,HC
5678,yyyy,1,2021/11/01,HC
1234,,zzzz,1,2021/11/01,HC
34567,xxxx,1,2021/11/02,HC
5678,yyyy,1,2021/11/02,HC
1234,,zzzz,1,2021/11/02,HC
```

This is the formula i have written

```
sumIf({count_value},
ifelse(((extract('YYYY',${Date})= 2020) or  (extract('YYYY',${Date})= 2021 and extract('MM',${Date})<11)),(type = 'HC'), 
ifelse((extract('YYYY',${Date})>2020 and extract('MM',${Date})>10),
(type= 'HC' and date = now()),(type= 'HC'))))
```

What we are missing here is the Month end employee count for November if the month moves to December.  For this logic we only get current  date employee count for all years after November 2021

Answer (score 0):

I added a few rows to your data so we have December as well to check your problem. My solution was to create two calculated fields:

- max-date-per-month
  `maxOver(date,[month],PRE_AGG)`
- count-per-date
  `sumOver({count_value},[date],PRE_AGG)`

And simply make a table from them (screenshot):
[Count-per-date by Max-date-per-month Quicksight table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqQHF.png)

This gives you the Count of employees on the Maximum date of each month, so the end of the month for past months and today's data for the current month.

You can either add filter code into the count formula for type='HC' or apply a filter to the visual. Note, you might have to change the "PRE-AGG" part of the calculated fields depending on how you do your filtering, Cheers.